# How do I add flash_player_sa_linux_debug.x86_64.tar.gz to the Open with application list?

Tags: default-programs

I would like to be able to set flashplayerdebugger as the default program to open swf files.  I would like it so when I double-clicked on a swf it would use the program I want.  How do I add the flashplayerdebugger to the "Open with..." menu when I right click.

EDIT: I have now done:

```
sudo install flashplayerdebugger /usr/local/bin
```

So now I can call flashplayerdebugger from any folder in terminal, but I am still stuck with how to manually set a file association to it for swf files.

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; and `.tar.gz` is usually seen with tarballs & not expanded executables; are you sure you've installed the tarball on your *unstated* system.

Comment: The end of life of Adobe Flash has been well advertised for 31 December 2020. Flash was discontinued and most OS removed support for it on or before this date.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu, does it matter what version?  I know Flash is EOL that's why I am using a offline player to play the swf files I am downloading from Kongregate.  It doesn't really matter if its just flash, I would like to know a simple way to add programs manually that permits me to then right-click on a given file type and then select that stand-alone/portable program as the default for that file type.

Comment: If you're talking about changes to your GUI (ie. new features such as right-click menu options) then the OS/release really does matter, as each version of Ubuntu comes with a different version of the default desktop (GNOME since 17.10). If you haven't been watching the updates on GNOME, they add & remove features as they try & perfect the UI. Use the method appropriate for your *unstated* release then, as we don't know what you're using we cannot accurately advise.

Comment: I was hoping for a simple way to do it on all versions, as I have several PC's with different versions.  These being 16.04, 20.04 and now just more recently 22.04 as I had issues with 22.10

Comment: You have to do two things: a) check is SWF a registered MIME-type on your systems, see directory /usr/share/mime/ .  If swf is not listed, you need to create the XML file yourself and install using xdg-utils. b) associate the MIME-type with a program by creating in entry in /etc/xdg/mineapps.list .
Sorry for not being able to provide more details, but I haven't done this for ages, so I can give you a more detailed step-by-step guide,

Comment: In the usr/share/applications/defaults.list it has a line application/x-shockwave-flash=org.gnome.Totem.desktop do I change org.gnome.Totem.desktop to something else or edit the .desktop file wherever it is?  I already have xdg-utils installed.